# Как вывести результат запроса из бд, в шаблон Django

Tags: python, sql, django, шаблоны

Всем доброго дня!

Я новичок в Django. Столкнулся с проблемой (не пониманием) того, как я могу вывести результат запроса из бд в шаблон Django.

У меня есть такая модель в **Django**:

**models.py**

```
 #Cеместры
 class SemesterModel(models.Model):
    number_semester = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Номер семестра")
    hours_maximum = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Максимум часов")
    hours_solo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для самостоятельной работы")
    hours_consultation = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для консультаций")
    hours_compulsory = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Обязательные часы")
    hours_lessons = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для лекций")
    hours_practical = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для практических работ")
    hours_seminar = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для семинаров")
    hours_course_work = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для курсовых работ")
    hours_individual_project = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Часы для индивидуальных проектов")
    subject_id = models.ForeignKey(SubjectModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    @property
    def hours(self):
        return self.hours_maximum + self.hours_solo + self.hours_compulsory + self.hours_consultation + self.hours_lessons + self.hours_practical + self.hours_seminar + self.hours_course_work + self.hours_individual_project

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Семестр'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Семестры'
 #Группы
 class GroupModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True,blank=True)
    year_id = models.ForeignKey(YearModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(CourseModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    special_id = models.ForeignKey(SpecialModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    educational_part_id = models.ForeignKey(EducationalPartModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date_autumn = models.DateField(verbose_name='Начало весеннеого семестра')
    end_date_autumn = models.DateField(verbose_name='Конец весеннеого семестра')
    start_date_spring = models.DateField(verbose_name='Начало осеннего семестра')
    end_date_spring = models.DateField(verbose_name='Конец осеннего семестра')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Группа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Группы'
#Нагрузка
 class TeacherLoadModel(models.Model):
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(GroupModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester_id = models.ForeignKey(SemesterModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Педагогическая нагрузка"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Нагрузка преподавателей'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Нагрузка преподавателей'
```

И есть такой запрос из базы:

```
 SELECT sem.number_semester as 'Номер семестра', gr.name as 'Название группы', us.username as 'ФИО', sub.name as 'Предмет', sem.hours_maximum+sem.hours_solo+sem.hours_consultation+sem.hours_compulsory+sem.hours_lessons+sem.hours_practical+sem.hours_seminar+sem.hours_course_work+sem.hours_individual_project as 'Часы'
 FROM main.main_teacherloadmodel tl, main.main_groupmodel gr, main.main_semestermodel sem, main.auth_user us, main.main_subjectmodel sub 
 where sem.number_semester = 1 
 and tl.group_id_id = gr.id 
 and us.id = tl.teacher_id_id 
 and tl.semester_id_id = sem.id 
 and sub.id = sem.subject_id_id
```

Как я могу интерпретировать данный запрос в Python Django, для вывода его в шаблон,  таким образом, чтобы результат не изменился, вот что я пытался сделать, но это оказалось без успешным.
Создал вью, в которую передал все данные из моделей выше.
**views.py**

```
def plan(request,group_id):
group = get_object_or_404(GroupModel, pk = group_id)
################################
groups = GroupModel.objects.all()
teacherload = TeacherLoadModel.objects.all()
semesters = SemesterModel.objects.all()
teachers = User.objects.all()
subjects = SubjectModel.objects.all()
hours = SemesterModel.hours
#################################
context = {"groups" : groups, "group" : group,  "semesters" : semesters, "hours": hours, "subjects": subjects, "teacherload":teacherload, "teachers" : teachers}
return render(request, 'main/deportament/plan.html',context)
```

Затем приступил к выводу данной таблицы, в html шаблон:

```
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for tl in teacherload %}
                    <td>1</td>
                    {% if tl.group_id == group.id%}
                        <td>{{ group.name }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% for teacher in teachers %}
                        {% if tl.teacher_id == teacher.id %}
                            <td>{{teacher.username}}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for semester in semesters %}
                        {% if tl.semester_id == semester.id %}
                            <td>Семестр {{semester.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{ hours }}</td>
                        {% endif %}           
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Ожидал увидеть следующий результат:
[image: Таблица]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже не умею пока делать красивые фильтры, но закинул ваши модельки себе в учебный джанго проект. Создал через админку объекты и вот что получилось.

models.py

```
class SemesterModel(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    number_semester = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Номер семестра")
    hours_maximum = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Максимум часов")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} '.format(self.subject,self.number_semester)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cеместр'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Семестры'
```

```
class GroupModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} '.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Группа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Группы'
```

```
class TeacherLoadModel(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(SemesterModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} '.format(self.teacher)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Препод'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Преподы'
```

urls.py

```
path("get/semester/<int:pk>/",GetSemestrPageView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
class GetSemestrPageView(TemplateView):
    """"""
    template_name = 'app_name/your_page.html'
    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        current_semester = SemesterModel.objects.get(id=pk)
        teacher = TeacherLoadModel.objects.filter(semester=current_semester)
        teacher=teacher.first()
        print('номер семестра',teacher.semester.number_semester)
        print('фио',teacher,'предмет',teacher.semester.subject,'часы',teacher.semester.hours_maximum)
        context['teacher'] = teacher
        return context
```

```
номер семестра 7
фио root  предмет Операционные системы и среды часы 48
```

В шаблоне просто получите объект {{teacher}}

Comment: Вы хорошо разбираетесь в Django? 
Можно с вами как то связаться, чтобы решить проблему некоторого функционала в моем Сайте